# Как выбрать все поля из таблицы в базе данных кроме одного, не перечисляя их?

Tags: mysql

Как выбрать все поля из таблицы в базе данных кроме одного, не перечисляя их.
Есть ли такая функция в MySQL?

Comment: Тут почитайте http://www.sql-ex.ru/help/select20.php?Lang=0

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        'SELECT ',
        (
            SELECT
                GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)
            FROM
                INFORMATION_SCHEMA. COLUMNS
            WHERE
                TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database'
            AND TABLE_NAME = 'table'
            AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('field')
            ORDER BY
                ORDINAL_POSITION
        ),
        ' FROM table'
    ) INTO @asd;
PREPARE newsql FROM @asd;
EXECUTE newsql;
```

где database - база данных, table - таблица, field - поле (столбец), который исключаем. Решение так себе, но работает.

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Нет такого способа. Придется вытаскивать все, либо перечислять.

UPD:
Хотя на английском SO был предложен [способ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1712243/3116253) =)